# How to ftp the file by appending the number at the end of the file using JCL

Tags: mainframe, jcl

We have Job which will run 4 times in a day, so now at every time it runs it creates a file and ftp the file as "LCD_BI_ORDERINFO_&OYMD._&OHHMM._001_01.txt " , So now i want the file to be sent as below:

after each run it should append with 01 02 03 and 04.txt at the end of the file as below.

```
LCD_BI_ORDERINFO_&OYMD._001_01.txt
LCD_BI_ORDERINFO_&OYMD._001_02.txt
LCD_BI_ORDERINFO_&OYMD._001_03.txt
LCD_BI_ORDERINFO_&OYMD._001_04.txt
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot do it with JCL as that is not the sort of thing JCL does. You would need  program. However, if you substituted the sequence number with a time variable then perhaps system variables could be usd by the reader/interpreter as the JCL is read in.

Comment: If you were to use a GDG, every time the job runs the file name would have a different generation number appended to it.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your existing job as a cataloged procedure with a parameter indicating the suffix number.  Now, instead of one job that runs four times a day, have four different sets of execution JCL for the cataloged proc, each of which will execute once a day, specifying the correct suffix number.

Schedule these in your shop's job scheduler.